# Check if div has specific text after been added with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to check if a specific div has an specific text that has been added with ajax.

This is the ajax function code:

```
    $(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '#JS_couponSubmit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.data('text', $this.text());
            $this.text('Cargando...');
            var $form = $('#JS_couponForm');

            $.ajax({
                url: $form.attr('data-action'),
                data: {
                    'coupon_code': $('#JS_couponCode').val(),
                    'view_cart': 'front_cart/v_cart'
                },
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function(response) {
                    $this.text($this.data('text'));
                    $('#JS_cart').replaceWith(response.htmlCart);
                    $('#JS_couponResponse')
                    .html(response.message)
                    .addClass(response.message?'success':'error');
                    $('#JS_couponForm th p').addClass('active');
                    $('#JS_couponForm td').show(100);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

This code adds the text `No existe este código` (or another text if the coupon code is correct but for the purpose of this question I just use this one) to `#JS_couponResponse`.

So I have tried using this function inside the `success: function(response) { }` but it simply does not work:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
  $('#JS_couponResponse:contains("No existe este código")').each(function () {
      alert("Has text");
  });
},1000);
```

I also tried this, again inside the `success: function(response) { }`:

```
var $myDiv = $('#JS_couponResponse:contains("No existe este código")');
if ( $myDiv.length){
  alert("Has text");
}
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `if($('#JS_couponResponse').text() == 'No existe este código')) { // do your stuff`?

Comment: You can use `indexOf` `if($('#JS_couponResponse').text().indexOf('No existe este códig')>-1) { //do something}`

Comment: @D4V1D does it have to be inside the `success` function? I have put it but still doesn't work

Comment: @anpsmn does it have to be inside the success function? I have put it there but still doesn't work

Comment: Yes, I'd put this inside the `success: function() { }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with `:contains` is that it cannot cope with accented characters, like `ó`.

If you avoid those any of your current approaches will work as-is:

e.g.

```
var $myDiv = $('#JS_couponResponse:contains("No existe este")');
if ( $myDiv.length){
  alert("Has text");
}
```

Comment: This was the problem! it works now! haha been trying this the whole morning... thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can add use `indexOf` in your success method.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.JS_couponResponse').each(function(){
    if($(this).text().indexOf("No existe este códig")>-1) {
      $(this).css("color","green");
    }
    else {
          $(this).css("color","red");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="JS_couponResponse"> No existe este códig  efff fdg sdgs</div>

<div class="JS_couponResponse">efff fdg sdgs</div>
```

Comment: The problem with your approach is that the text `No existe este código` is added after I click on a button in the page. So the text is not shown on document.ready but after the user clicks on a button with the ajax function I put in the question

Comment: Yeah you can move that in your success method. I have used document.ready for the demo to work here.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr('data-action'),
            data: {
                'coupon_code': $('#JS_couponCode').val(),
                'view_cart': 'front_cart/v_cart'
            },
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(response) {
                $this.text($this.data('text'));
                $('#JS_cart').replaceWith(response.htmlCart);
                $('#JS_couponResponse')
                .html(response.message)
                .addClass(response.message?'success':'error');
                $('#JS_couponForm th p').addClass('active');
                $('#JS_couponForm td').show(100);

                // Code to add in your success callback if you have several div ".couponResponse"
                $('.JS_couponResponse').each(function() {
                    if($(this).text() == 'No existe este código'))
                    {
                        alert('Has text');
                    }
                });

                // Code to add in your success callback if you have only one div "#couponResponse"
                if($('#JS_couponResponse').text() == 'No existe este código'))
                {
                    alert('Has text');
                }
        });
```

Note that you would need to switch from `id="JS_couponResponse"` to `class="JS_couponResponse"` if you have several `div`s. HTML `ID` are **unique** inside the DOM.